# How to mock and inject correctly two maps with different data types in a class using mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, hashmap, mockito

I am unable to mock and inject two maps using mockito. I have a simple java class which is using strategy pattern implemented using Hashmap in two places. The method in question which needs to be tested for this class is using both the Hashmaps.

Now when I am using @Mock annotation to initialize the mocked Map and using @InjectMocks for injecting the mocks in the class what is happening is that only one of the Map is getting injected and being used in both the places instead of both getting passed and matched using their data types, which I guess is the intended behaviour.

Is this a known mockito Bug or am I doing something incorrectly. Do tell me if I need to elaborate further.

Comment: please add the code to visualize what you tried so far

Comment: One possible solution would be not to rely on the mocking mechanism but using, for example, `Whitebox.setInternalState(myObject, "fieldName1", myMap1");` (and the same with the other field) directly in the `@Before` method. Thas approach uses reflection to magically put the values into the fields. Of course, the need to do so is a code smell, but that's another problem.

Comment: don't create mock objects of Map rather create new objects and inject them by calling actual methods, that would suffice your requirement